# How to differentiate this double integral from Christopher Bishop's Pattern Recognition book.

Tags: calculus

In Bishop's book Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning, the following can be found on page 46:

(1):
$$
J[f] = \iint\{f(\mathbf{x}) - t\}^2p(\mathbf{x},t)\mathrm{d}t \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}
$$

He then differentiates this expression with respect to $f(\mathbf{x})$:

(2):
$$
\frac{\delta J[f]}{\delta f(\mathbf{x})} = 2 \int \{f(\mathbf{x}) - t\}p(\mathbf{x}, t)\mathrm{d}t
$$

My question is how to do this differentiation. One of the things I'm not getting is how the integral for $\mathbf{x}$ disappears even though we're not differentiating w.r.t. $\mathbf{x}$.

If someone could provide a step by step derivation from (1) to (2) that would be very appreciated.

Thanks :)

EDIT:

So I've tried to use the Euler-Lagrange equation like this:

$$
L = \int{\{f(\mathbf{x}) - t\}^2p(\mathbf{x},t)\mathrm{d}t}
$$
$$
\frac{\delta J}{\delta f(\mathbf{x})} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial f} - \frac{d}{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}}\frac{\partial L}{\partial f^\prime}
$$
(3):
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial f} = \frac{\partial}{\partial f} \int{\{f(\mathbf{x}) - t\}^2p(\mathbf{x},t)\mathrm{d}t}  = 2\int{\{f(\mathbf{x}) - t\} p(\mathbf{x}, t)}\mathrm{d}t
$$

This implies that $\frac{d}{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}}\frac{\partial L}{\partial f^\prime} = \frac{d}{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}}\frac{\partial}{\partial f^\prime}\int{\{f(\mathbf{x}) - t\}^2p(\mathbf{x},t)\mathrm{d}t} = 0$. But I have no idea of how to prove this. Any ideas?

Comment: This is a functional derivative. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative, the formula before the table of contents

Comment: Thanks Yuriy. I used the formula but did not quite get to where I wanted. I've shown my calculations in an edit. Any ideas of how to proceed?

Comment: Why are you using $\delta$ on the right hand side? Are you confusing the functional derivative, the partial derivative and the total derivative?

Comment: Yes, I'm definitely confusing them. I've changed it now, hope it's right. I left $\frac{\delta}{\delta y}K$ because $K$ is a function of $y$ and $\mathbf{x}$

Comment: No, it's not right... Please use the exact same notation as in Wikipedia, and then look up what they mean and how to apply them. Functional derivative can only be applied to functionals, not functions

Comment: Okay, I've changed all the notation to comply with Wikipedia. The way I see it, I've only applied the Euler formula to $J$, which is a functional, because it's a function of the function $f$. So I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. This is all very new to me which is why I'm a bit slow.

Comment: You are right that J is a functional. But L is not a functional. It's a function, and you should differentiate it w.r.t. $f$ as if it's a variable

Comment: Okay, so you are saying that my differentiation in (3) is incorrect? I can't see how that is the case...

Comment: Sandi, as far as I see everything is fine and fits with the book. I just object to your notation. It should be $$\frac{\delta J}{\delta f(\mathbf{x})} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial f} - \frac{d}{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}}\frac{\partial L}{\partial f^\prime}
$$ And your last question is immediately answered, because $L$ doesn't explicitly depend of $f'$